# Conditional Formatting Rule Not Working on One Cell

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, excel-2016

I have a perplexing problem with one of my Excel spreadsheets. I have a "task list" spreadsheet, with conditional formatting to highlight items that are near their due date and overdue. One cell in my entire worksheet is not allowing the conditional formatting, and I am not sure why. It does not matter what is in the cell.

I have tried:

- deleting the table row
- deleting the entire row
- re-typing the cell
- re-sorting the cells
- deleting and re-creating the rule
- verifying that the rule is applied to that cell

Any ideas as to what is causing this?

The affected cell is D5. You can download the spreadsheet here: [Google Drive download link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11DPK7XRH6P4Owy_hfGvesKTF8bw_f9S8)

[image]

Comment: Yes I have done that. I switched to a different format and switched back. I also used format painter from another cell to that one.

Comment: Does the cell change to a serial number if you change the format to `Number` or `General`?

Comment: @urdearboy yes it does

Comment: hm. Well my last question is does this cell actually fit the conditional format criteria?

Comment: @urdearboy I have added a link to the file if you are interested in downloading it and trying a few things. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @urdearboy yes it does fit the criteria. If I sort the sheet differently, the conditional formatting gets applied to that information. It is specifically tied to cell D5, regardless of the information that is stored there...

Comment: for troubleshooting, what if you go to the cell below it, hit CTRL+C, then go to the problem cell and hit CTRL+ALT+V and double click `Values`, then hit CTRL+ALT+V again and double click `Formats` ... ?

Comment: **What is the conditional formatting criteria for that cell?** Perhaps you could add to your question a cropped image of the formatting rule for that cell? Based on your last comment, I bet this has something to do with absolute/relative cell references.

Comment: @ashleedawg =AND(ROW()>5,$D1<TODAY()+1,$D1<>"") It applies a red cell fill and bold text to any date before today. I tried your copy-special paste suggestion, but that did not fix it.

Comment: @JeffMiller - instead of `ROW()>5`use `ROW()>=5`. I can't see the row numbers in your image but if that's row 5 then that's part of the issue. If not, please post an image showing the row/column headings.  Also "before today" would be "<TODAY()" . The +1 makes it "before tomorrow".

Answer (score 1):

Since that's cell `D5`, instead of `ROW()>5` you should use `ROW()>=5`.

Also "before today" would be `<TODAY()` . The `+1` makes it *"before tomorrow"*.

---

It's kind of unusual to have a row number in there at all.  I assume you did that so you could apply the format to the whole column but if the extra cells are not dates (like, are just titles) then they shouldn't be affected by the conditional formatting.

If it was *me*, I would clear all the formatting from that column and in `D5` add the simple conditional formatting criteria `=D5<TODAY()`, then copy that cell, click heading `D` to select the entire column, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and *Paste Formats*.

Better yet, only apply the Conditional Formatting to the cells that need it, not the whole column.  Conditional Formatting increases the file size and slow down calculation more that one would think. (I was argued that but was proven wrong!)